# In generic repository pattern in ASP.NET MVC, how do I pass city, state, country list item in view, already pass T values "HallProfile"

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

With a generic repository pattern, I am trying to add new record. The model class has foreign keys `HallProfile`, `City`, `State`, `Country` there are four tables with foreign keys.

How can I pass city, state, country list item (dropdown list) to a view?

```
private BAL.interfaces.IHallBook<HallProfile> fromintrface;

    public AllHallListController()
    {
        this.fromintrface = new ManupulationRecord<HallProfile>();
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.listdata = from x in fromintrface.GetAllList() select x;
        return View(from x in fromintrface.GetAllList() select x);
    }

    // AllHallList/AddNewHallRecord
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult AddNewHallRecord(ClsCityList city)
    { 
        /*
        How to get City list, State list, Country list for use 
        from three different tables, but use foreign keys 
        with this HallProfile table  
        */
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddNewHallRecord(HallProfile hall)
    {
        fromintrface.AddNewRecord(hall);
        fromintrface.SaveAsRecord();
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you reformat the question so we get a clearer picture of the current problem and what you are **actually** trying to do? See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

```
    [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult AddNewHallRecord(ClsCityList city)
        { 
            /*
            How to get City list, State list, Country list for use 
            from three different tables, but use foreign keys 
            with this HallProfile table  
            */
List<CiTyModel> city= (from x in fromintrface.GetAllList() select x).ToList().FirstOrDefault(n=>n.cityID == city.Id);

SelectList cityList = new SelectList(cate, "Id", "CityName");

ViewBag.CityList = cateList;
            return View();
        }
```

And in view,

```
@Html.DropDownList("CityDropDown", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>) ViewBag.CityList , new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: Sir not worked this code please more code click on this ling same topic

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57985873/how-to-achieve-cascading-dropdown-list-in-generic-repository-pattern-mvc-net-ent

Comment: now error State Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'ModelData.HallProfile' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ModelData.ClsCityList>'

Comment: Yes Sir

  `[Table("tblCity")]
   public class ClsCityList
    {
        [Key]
        public int cityId { get; set; }
        public string cityNme { get; set; }
        public int statId { get; set; }

        public ICollection<HallProfile> HallSets { get; set; }
    }`

also please click on this link for more code code

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57985873/how-to-achieve-cascading-dropdown-list-in-generic-repository-pattern-mvc-net-ent

Comment: can you show T GetRecord(int id);
    IEnumerable<T> GetByCity(string city);
    IEnumerable <T>GetAllList(); ?

Comment: Sir I Passed T values as a HallProfile

private BAL.interfaces.IHallBook<HallProfile> fromintrface;

`public T GetRecord(int id)
        {
            T model = dbEntity.Find(id);
            return model;
        }`

Now same Controller allow only one model class code

Comment: sir just need to using generic repository show registration form it should available city state country drop down list
if you want change any code any or add new code just want desire output