# How to achieve cascading dropdown list in generic repository pattern Mvc.Net entity framework?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

How to create a cascading DropDownList in generic repository pattern using EF Code first, where one registration form in that available country state and city option and this get from different database table
public class ManupulationRecord : IHallBook where T : class
where  I passed "HallProfile" ENtity Model
now How achieve City Country State cascading drop down list Adding New Record in View

```
namespace ModelData
{
   [Table("tblHallProfile")]
  public class HallProfile
    {


        [Key]
        public int profileId { get; set; }
        public string hallName { get; set; } 
        public string thumbnailImgPath { get; set; }
        public string hallOwnerName { get; set; }
        public string adress { get; set; }
        public string contactNumber { get; set; }
        public string emailAdress { get; set; }
        public string website { get; set; }

        public string hallCategory { get; set; }
        public string createdDate { get; set; }

        public int vehecleParking { get; set; }
        public string foodTypeVegNonVej { get; set; }
        public string decription { get; set; } 
        public decimal cost { get; set; }
        public string serviceTime { get; set; }
        public string OtherService { get; set; }
        public int publicCapacity { set; get; }
        public int cityId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("cityId")]
        public virtual ClsCityList cityIdt { get; set; }

        public int StateId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("StateId")]
        public virtual ClsStateList stateIdt { get; set; }

        public int CountryId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("CountryId")]
        public virtual  ClsCountryList CountryIdt { get; set; }

        public int areaId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("areaId")]
        public virtual ClsArea areaIdt { get; set; }
}
```

In Interface Calss

```
public interface IHallBook<T> where T : class
{
    T GetRecord(int id);
    IEnumerable<T> GetByCity(string city);
    IEnumerable <T>GetAllList();
    void AddNewRecord(T model);
    void UpdateRecord(T model);
    void DeleteRecord(int id);

    void SaveAsRecord();
 }
```

Manupulation Calss is Here

```
public class ManupulationRecord<T> : IHallBook<T> where T : class
    {
        private DataBaseContext dbdata;
        private DbSet<T> dbEntity;

        public ManupulationRecord()
        {
            dbdata = new DataBaseContext();
            dbEntity = dbdata.Set<T>();
        } 
        public void AddNewRecord(T model)
        {
            dbEntity.Add(model);
        }
```

controller

```
public class AllHallListController : Controller
    {
        // GET: /AllHallList/Index
        private BAL.interfaces.IHallBook<HallProfile> fromintrface;

        public AllHallListController()
        {
            this.fromintrface = new ManupulationRecord<HallProfile>();
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.listdata = from x in fromintrface.GetAllList() select x;
            return View(from x in fromintrface.GetAllList() select x);
        }
        // AllHallList/AddNewHallRecord

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult AddNewHallRecord(ClsCityList city)
        { 
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddNewHallRecord(HallProfile hall)
        {
            fromintrface.AddNewRecord(hall);
            fromintrface.SaveAsRecord();
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try add to controller:  `private BAL.interfaces.IHallBook<ClsCityList> cityList;`
and in action AddNewHallRecord:

```
ViewBag.CityList = (from x in cityList.GetAllList() select x);
SelectList selectlistCity = new SelectList(city, "Id", "CityName");
ViewBag.CityList = selectlistCity;
```

and in view:

```
@Html.DropDownList("CityDropDown", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>) ViewBag.CityList , new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: Sir it work but need same controller

sir just need to using generic repository show registration form it should available city state country drop down list if you want change any code any or add new code just want desire output

Comment: Please sir help me

Comment: i don't understand what do you mean, in action AddNewHallRecord(ClsCityList city) you want City list, State list, Country list through ClsCityList city ? Can you give me picture of your interface.